# How many Discipline points does a newly embraced ghoul get?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

On page 500 of the 20th Anniversary book, under "I *Was* Embraced Yesterday", it has some ambiguous wording. That is, I'm not sure how discipline points are meant to be handled. For instance, regarding attributes and abilities:

> When a ghoul character is Embraced, give them any Attribute and Ability points necessary to raise them to the starting values for vampires.

That's quite clear to me - no problem at all. However, we have this about disciplines:

> Embraced ghouls also receive the same Discipline points as a starting vampire. They retain any Disciplines learned as a ghoul when they are Embraced, including Potence.

Does that mean they receive one additional discipline point, because vampires start with three and ghouls start with two, or does that mean they receive the three vampires normally receive on top of their two?

Comment: Are you only interested in RAW for V20? There are supplements in Revised (particularly *Ghouls: Fatal Addiction*) which contain alternate mechanics, some of which mesh perfectly with V20 and others less so.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd be interested in other sources, but only V20 would be applicable to this group. We've all agreed to only use that book for this game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### An embraced ghoul receives three discipline points.

The part of:

> necessary to raise them to the starting values for vampires.

strictly refers to Attribute and Ability points, nothing else. Hence, an embraced ghoul receives three Disicpline points (getting a total of at least 5!).

You must see the embrace (which turns him/her into a fullfledged vampire) as an experience that deepens his/her understanding of the Blood and all that it entails (such as Disciplines and how they work).